# Invalid filter: 'revision'

Tags: python, django

When using the following code:

```
 {% with ""|add:revision.width|add:"x"|revision.height as dimensions %}


 {% thumbnail revision.image dimensions as thumb %}
 {% endwith %}
```

I receive the following error:

```
Django Version: 1.6.11
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Invalid filter: 'revision'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in find_filter, line 366
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.9
```

Why? And what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your last applied filter in the chain (`revision.height`).

Replace:

```
{% with ""|add:revision.width|add:"x"|revision.height as dimensions %}
```

with:

```
{% with ""|add:revision.width|add:"x"|add:revision.height as dimensions %}
```

---

You can also assign variables to `revision.width` and `revision.height`:

```
{% with width=revision.width height=revision.height %}
    {% with ""|add:width|add:"x"|add:height as dimensions %}
        ...
    {% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
```